# Django, a model class which inherits abstract model class can be also abstract?

Tags: django, model

AbstractBaseA -> AbstractBaseB -> ConcreateC1
AbstractBaseA -> AbstractBaseB -> ConcreateC2

All the above classes are django models.

Is it safe to abstractly(?) inherit another abstract model class in django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

> Of course, you can make an abstract base class that inherits from another abstract base class. You just need to remember to explicitly set abstract=True each time.

[Models | Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/)

Updated links for [2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/) and [3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/)

Comment: @Danial Robinson, Link is broken.